# Enable bypass proxy server and notify IE for the change

Tags: c, internet-explorer, winapi

I am trying to use the Internet Explorer Options API to set the **LAN Settings** based on this [example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/setting-and-retrieving-internet-options).

I was able to set the proxy address and the exception but I want to enable the `Bypass proxy server for local addresses` checkbox and also notify Internet Explorer for the change so I don't have to close it and open it again.

I suppose I need to use another option from `INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION` structure, but no idea what I should use.

[image]

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST connList;
    DWORD bufSize = sizeof(connList);

    connList.dwSize = sizeof(connList);
    connList.pszConnection = NULL; 
    connList.dwOptionCount = 3;
    connList.pOptions = (INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION*)malloc(sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION) * 3);

    if (connList.pOptions == NULL)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Memory allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;

    }

    connList.pOptions[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
    connList.pOptions[0].Value.dwValue = PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT |
        PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;

    connList.pOptions[1].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
    connList.pOptions[1].Value.pszValue = L"https://internal.com.co:80";

    connList.pOptions[2].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
    connList.pOptions[2].Value.pszValue = L"local";

    BOOL internetOption;

    internetOption = InternetSetOptionW(NULL,
        INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
        &connList,
        bufSize);

    if (internetOption != TRUE)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Faile to set the option with code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    free(connList.pOptions);

    wprintf(L"Done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the string `<local>` including the `<` and `>` signs to the exception list, e.g. `<local>;*.microsoft.com`.

Comment: Awesome! And do you have any idea about notifying IE to make the change without reopen it?

Comment: I believe you should first reset the proxy settings ("PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT") before setting new values.